# Why does Facebook return null end_time for event?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

When I query Facebook for the 256996217750754 eid using fql, it returns end_time as null:

`SELECT eid, name, pic_small, pic_big, pic_square, pic, host, description, start_time, end_time, creator, update_time, location, venue, privacy from event where eid=256996217750754`

returns:

```
...
"start_time": "2012-09-01T22:00:00-0400",
"end_time": null,
...
```

However, when I query the graph it returns accurate:

`https://graph.facebook.com/256996217750754?access_token=<access_token>`

returns:

```
...
start_time: "2012-09-01T22:00:00",
end_time: "2012-09-02T01:00:00",
...
```

Does anyone know why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe Donn Lee is partially correct. According to a Facebook developer [article](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2012/08/01/platform-migration--events-timezone-support/), the "end_time" is always defined for an event. However, this will be going away by October 30, 2012.

Notice the difference between Donn Lee's response from the graph and my own.

My response, which has "Events Timezone" disabled:

```
...
"start_time": "2012-09-01T22:00:00-0400",
"end_time": null,
...
```

Donn Lee's response, which likely has "Events Timezone" enabled:

```
...
"start_time": "2012-09-01T22:00:00-0400",
...
```

This setting can be found under "Migrations" on the "Advanced" settings page for a Facebook application:

[image]

## Conclusion

It looks like I need to migrate my code to support Facebook's [new event time conventions](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2012/08/01/platform-migration--events-timezone-support/):

1. handle ISO-8601 **with offsets**
2. to expect no "end_time" if none is specified.

Answer (score 1):

`end_time` is null when the event doesn't have the optional end time defined.
Moreover, when I query the graph for that event, I do not see `end_time` which is consistent with FQL returning null:

```
{
   "id": "256996217750754",
   "owner": {
      "name": "Buffalo Wings & Rings Morrisville, NC",
      "category": "Restaurant/cafe",
      "id": "136674116345739"
   },
   "name": "UFC 151 on Pay Per View - Jones vs. Henderson",
   "description": "Main Card -\nJones vs Henderson\nJohnson vs Castillo\nMizugaki vs Hougland\nSiver vs Yagin\nLineker vs Urushitani\nPrelims - \nCruickshank vs Martinez\nRoller vs Volkmann",
   "start_time": "2012-09-01T22:00:00-0400",
   "timezone": "America/New_York",
   "location": "Buffalo Wings & Rings Morrisville, NC",
   "venue": {
      "id": "136674116345739"
   },
   "privacy": "OPEN",
   "updated_time": "2012-08-02T14:37:21+0000"
}
```

I used:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/256996217750754?access_token=AAACEdEose...
```